# Scroll to page depending on button that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain to me how I can use the jquery scroll-to to make the buttons on the yellow menu scroll to their corresponding sections (i.e distribution to the pink block)

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/VXkW5/5/

I think its something like this:

```
$(".nav").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").offset().top + $(".section").height()
    }, 500);
});
```

But I dont know how to relate it to it's relevant section based on the link that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/VXkW5/12/)

First of all, ID need to be unique in the page. I see both  as well as  uses same ID

so i have made change & Just add the corresponding div id to the href tag, it will take to that particular div on click

```
<a href="#posting" class="nav">posting</a>
<a href="#distribution" class="nav">distribution</a>
<a href="#application" class="nav">applicantions</a>
```

In terms of jQuery:

```
$(".nav").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var divId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top;
        }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a link like

```
<a href="#section1" class="nav">Click to jump to section 1</a>
```

And a section like

```
<div id="section1">
    <p>Section 1 content</p>
</div>
```

And handle the scroll to like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".nav").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();    
        var theHref = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(theHref).offset().top + $(".section").height()
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Note that the javascript block is optional - it simply allows you to use a smooth animation vs jump